# CSS/JS remove space before (automatic) line break/text wrap

Tags: javascript, css, alignment, spacing

I have 3 elements in a single line: 2 texts split by a divider.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>this is my extra long text</div>
    <div class="divider">|</div>
    <div>text2</div>
</div>
```

These elements are inside a container with a maximum width causing the texts to break/wrap if they are too long.

My problem:
As soon as the left text breaks the spacing from the left text to divider increases. I think this is because the text gets waraped after the white space but preserving the space in that line.

I made a fiddle to show my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/4857bb0s/15/

How can i fix this?

**Edit:**

It looks like (notice the unwanted space between the left text and the divider):

[image: what it looks like]

It should look like:

[image]

Comment: Why have them in two different elements if you'd like them to overlap?

Comment: because they should be able to wrap independently

Answer (score 0):

You could try 
   `style = "text-align: justify"` on your div with long text.

Comment: this just stretches the text

Comment: This is a really nice workaround but I think progmem is searching for a space replacement to reduce the size of the left div.